# Why is there RampanT Grammar and CapiTalization correction?

Tags: discussion

A lot of questions are un-necessarily edited very quickly in terms of grammar and caps. I understand making some questions more readable. Is there a reason for this obsessionality in moderators? (Other than a Paroxetine deficiency?)

Comment: Because we love you, rosser!

Comment: We also like coffee :)

Comment: "Unnecessarily" edited?  Are you intimating that questions with bad grammar and punctuation *ought* to stand?  I am curious why someone would prefer such a state of affairs.  If the concern is that dedicated editing might be altering the meaning of some questions, then let's air that and examine our options--but such a concern is not evident in the present question.

Comment: No it was a concern for the ongoing mental health of Moderators, that is all.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Officially it is because of the [broken windows rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Broken_windows_theory); a clean site seems more reliable and appealing to the visitors. And it seems to be working, since even the raw questions here look much better than on other SEs.

The truth is that I'm an obsessive editor (I've made a [disclaimer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/election/1#post-7215) during the moderator election), but this is only a [part of the whole story](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users?tab=editors&filter=year), and I am still [far from real records](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=editors&filter=year).

Answer (score 5):

The reason I contribute to the site is to create ongoing resources for future readers. Editing question so that they are clear helps achieve this goal.